# sed not activating in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

None of my sed calls seem to be activating on the document. I've checked and double checked the regex, it works in all the text editors I have available to me (Geany, Gedit, Notepad ++), anyone have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
antiword q.doc > q.txt
sed -i -e's/\[.*\]//g' q.txt # replace [...] with nothing
sed -i -e's/^[ \t]+[o][ \t]//g' q.txt # replace old word UL with nothing
sed -i -e's/^[ \t]+[•][ \t]//g' q.txt # replace old word UL with nothing
```

Bonus marks for showing me how to remove extra returns in the file such that there is only ever 1 line between elements that previously had 2 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you wrote your regex with Perl syntax or extended regular expression syntax in mind, but sed uses [basic regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). Depending on the implementation of sed you're using, the simplest solution would be to tell sed to use extended regular expressions with an `-E` (Mac OS X) or `-r` (GNU sed) flag. You may also need to make the `\t`s into literal tabs.

Comment: Or to correct the regex to be valid basic RE by changing `+` to `\+`.

Comment: @jamessan Not quite that simple. The change you suggest is a GNU extension, and not usually available in other implementations. Also, all the brackets need to be changed. POSIX BREs are *really* minimal, and the EREs aren't much richer.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber strange, because the recommendation to use -r works.

Comment: @Brandon That suggests you're using GNU sed, which supports quite a few extensions, including the `-r` flag to get extended regular expressions and several extra meta-characters for both BREs and EREs.  My comment to jamessan was about the limitations of traditional sed implementations, which have *very* bare-bones BREs, and about the differences in bracketing characters between BREs and EREs. Other implementations may be less rich, e.g., sed on Mac OS X can use EREs, but doesn't have the extended metacharacters that GNU sed offers.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Thanks for the detail here. I wasn't aware of any other type of RE, just ERE (from perl/R).

Comment: @Brandon Glad to help. Actually, Perl goes beyond EREs, really constituting its own class of regex; modern scripting languages and editors are often closer to Perl regex than EREs or BREs. And there are a lot of variations on all three types of regex...

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber making it that much more of a PITA to know which you're supposed to use in which situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU-sed:

Line 1) Works well here (deletes paired square brackets and everything in between).

Line 2 and 3) (

> From the manpage for `[`*list*`]`: The characters $, *, ., [, and \ are normally not special within list.
>   For example, [*] matches either ‘\’ or ‘*’, because the \ is not
>   special here.

Solution: Instead of `[ \t]` code: `[:space:]`